# SwingWorker not stopping

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

So guys i just got into swing worker and i don't know how to stop it i tried this `boolean` way. its not working can you guy's edit my code to a way that it will work or something! thanks alot!

There's no error showing its just not stopping!

```
class MessageBox {

    public static void infoBox(String infoMessage, String location)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage, "Message: " + location, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}

public class GUI extends JFrame 
{
    private JButton button1;
    private JPanel Gpanel;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JTextField howmany;
    private JLabel countlabel;
    private JLabel statuslabel;
    private JCheckBox anyEmail;
    private JButton stopButton;
    private boolean stopped;


    public GUI() {
        super("Program V0.1");
        this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("icon.png")).getImage());

        setContentPane(Gpanel);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                start();
            }
        });
        stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            stopped = true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void start() {
        SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                if (!stopped){
                    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(howmany.getText()); i++) {
                        if (anyEmail.isSelected()) {

                            URL url = null;
                            try {
                                String Hostemail = "http://example.com/";
                                url = new URL(Hostemail);
                            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Map<String, Object> variables = new LinkedHashMap<>();

                            variables.put("email", textField1.getText());
                            variables.put("fullname", "");
                            variables.put("pw", "");
                            variables.put("pw-conf", "");
                            variables.put("digest", "1");
                            variables.put("email-button", "Subscribe");

                            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
                            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : variables.entrySet()) {
                                if (postData.length() != 0) {
                                    postData.append('&');
                                }
                                try {
                                    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                postData.append('=');
                                try {
                                    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
                                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            byte[] postDataBytes = new byte[0];
                            try {
                                postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String line;
                            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                            try {
                                assert url != null;
                                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            try {
                                assert conn != null;
                                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache,private,Private");

                            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
                            conn.setDoOutput(true);
                            try {
                                conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            BufferedReader in = null;
                            try {
                                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            try {
                                assert in != null;
                                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                                    String success = "Your subscription request has been received";
                                    if (line.contains(success)) {
                                        countlabel.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            URL url = null;
                            try {
                                String Host = "http://example2.com";
                                url = new URL(Host);
                            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Map<String, Object> variables = new LinkedHashMap<>();

                            variables.put("strEmail", textField1.getText());

                            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
                            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : variables.entrySet()) {
                                if (postData.length() != 0) {
                                    postData.append('&');
                                }
                                try {
                                    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                postData.append('=');
                                try {
                                    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
                                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            byte[] postDataBytes = new byte[0];
                            try {
                                postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String line;
                            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                            try {
                                assert url != null;
                                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            try {
                                assert conn != null;
                                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache,private,Private");

                            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
                            conn.setDoOutput(true);
                            try {
                                conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            BufferedReader in = null;
                            try {
                                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            try {
                                statuslabel.setText("Sending Emails...");
                                assert in != null;
                                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                                    String success = "success";
                                    String error = "not";

                                    if (line.contains(success)) {
                                        countlabel.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                                    } else if (line.contains(error)) {
                                        MessageBox.infoBox("[Email Not Found]: " + textField1.getText(), "Error");
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                statuslabel.setText("Done");
                return null;
            }

        };
        worker.execute();
        if (stopped){
            worker.cancel(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling cancel on the worker?

Comment: thats the program man i don't know how to call it in the action listener :/ so i tried using bool

Comment: Then you need a reference to the running worker in order to call `cancel`  Change your `start` method so that it creates a `SwingWorker` assigned to a class instance variable, rather then a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is, that immediately after you have started the swingworker by calling the `worker.execute()` method you check if `stopped == true`. As the `execute()` method is non blocking the if-statement gets evaluated just  after the call to `execute()`. At this time, the value of stopped can only be `true`, thus your worker won't get canceled. One solution would be, to make your worker an instance member and do it more like this:

```
private SwingWorker worker;
// ...
stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (worker != null && !worker.isCanceled()) {
            worker.cancel(true);
        }
    }
});
```

Additionally if you have members that are accessed and changed from different threads you should synchronize that access.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of `SwingWorker`s [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) heritage and use `isCancelled` and `cancel` functionality...

```
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    int i = 0;
    while (!isCancelled() && i < howMany) {
        ...
```

In order to be able to cancel the worker, you will need a reference to it...

```
private SwingWorker worker;

//...

stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (worker != null) {
            worker.cancel(true);
        }
    }
});
```

Note, `SwingWorker` should not be accessing or referencing any UI components (in fact, you should avoid referencing any values outside of it's context where possible), because it runs in the background, you run the risk of (not only) violating the single thread rules of Swing, but also having the information you are relying on changed while you are processing it.

You should gather all the information that the `SwingWorker` needs and pass that information to it (via the constructor or setter methods) before you start it.  This means that the worker is running in isolation without the risk of other data changing which could cause other, random issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `stopped` is true once *per loop interation*, not once before the loop. You can rewrite your worker as:

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(howmany.getText()); i++) {
           if(stopped){return null;}
           //your existing loop contents
        }
    }
```

This will in turn stop the loop whenever it tries to perform its next iteration. However the current iteration will be finished unless you were to interrupt the thread or otherwise forcibly stop it.

In addition, you will need to make sure that stopped is marked as volatile where it is declared.

Comment: @MadProgrammer How is a for-loop in the OP's source code not a loop?

Comment: @ToxicSAS Note, the worker won't "suddenly" stop.  Until it has time to evaluate the state of `stopped`, the worker will continue executing the current loop iteration.  You could also make `stopped` `volatile` or use [`AtomicBoolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) to solve possible `Thread` memory referencing issues